# IE11 event trigger issue for focusOut, input

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

I have an input text box on which there are handlers for events like focusOut, input

Now, I expect the "input" event to be trigerred/handled first and then the "focusOut" (as I use the entered value in focusOut)

The above sequence works consistently on Chrome, FF. However, in IE11, the sequence is a bit unpredictable i.e. in certain cases, the focusOut triggers first and then the input

From what I observed, this is mostly when I enter the value in that field and directly click on the Submit btn on my form using my mouse.
Is that a known IE11 issue ?

Comment: Your explanation about the issue is not clear. We understand the onfocusout event but which another event you are using in your code? In which certain cases onfocusout event occurs first? If possible then try to provide any sample code to produce the issue. Only description is not helpful in this scenario. If you provide sample then we will again try to check the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: You can check the "input" event I am referring to on this page https://javascript.info/events-change-input

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are saying that onfocusout is executing first then oninput event.

I try to test this sample code with IE browser and it looks fine.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="input" onfocusout="alert(this.value)"> oninput: <span id="result"></span><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
<script>
  input.oninput = function() {
    result.innerHTML = input.value;
  };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image]

Let me know if I am missing anything. I will try to correct myself.